# How to randomize array with WP_Query

Tags: sql, wordpress

how to get the lasted portfolio post then randomize it ?

```
$args = array('numberposts' => 8,'post_type' => 'portfolio','orderby'=> 'id','order' => 'desc');

// get results
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: What do you mean by randomize it? You want the 8 latest posts, but random ones?

Comment: @Howlin Yes 8 latest posts, but random ones

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `'orderby'=> 'id'`, try `'orderby'=> 'rand'`.

Source: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters

You probably also should specify `'posts_per_page' => 8` instead of `numberposts`.

But maybe you want 8 latest posts, then choose one of the 8 at random. If so, this might work: (and specify `orderby` => 'ID' [capital letters])

```
$posts = $the_query->get_posts();
$rand_key = array_rand($posts);
```

then `$posts[$rand_key]` will randomly choose one of the 8 posts.

lastly, if you want 8 latest posts in random order, then try this:

```
$posts = $the_query->get_posts();
shuffle($posts)
```

Comment: yes @yitwail with rand i will get only random posts, i want the 8 latest posts, but random ones